# Location of project.json in Cocos2d-JS

Tags: cocos2d-x-js

I am learning Cocos2d-JS to develop web-based games with Javascript. In Cocos2d-JS there is `project.json` file which defines game configuration.

Is it possible to place this file in another location than the directory containing `index.html` or `main.js` and if so, where and how should I define the new path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out, the requirement of `project.json` is hardcoded into Cocos2d-JS internals and it should be located at the same directory (path) as the HTML document. There are no configuration settings allowing to overwrite it.

However, it is possible to change the reference to `project.json` in the `cc.game._initConfig` method, as the source of Cocos2d-JS is open.

Comment: this is just what i've done recently